# Android push view up

Tags: android, xml, view, push, android-softkeyboard

in my android application I am having a login page where I need to push the entire view up when the keyboard gets open now what happends is.. I have two edittext one for username and another for password and two textview below for forgot password and new user so when I click on username edittext keyboard open and hiding the password edittext and textviews, what I need is keyboard needs to push up the entire views.. so user dont need to press the back button to hide the keybord for going to password edit text..

What I tried...
I gave

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

in android manifest in activity and

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in oncreate, but still it is hiding the edittext and textviews... I f anyone know how to overcome this situation please help

my xml is giving below

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/red">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionContent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginNow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAboutUs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="LOGIN NOW"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginNow">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edittext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"/>



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edittext"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:text="@string/login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewIfNewUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/ifnewuser"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNewUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewIfNewUser"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewIfNewUser"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/newuser"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_red"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewIfForgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewIfNewUser"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/ifforgotpassword"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewForgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewIfForgotPassword"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewIfForgotPassword"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/forgotpassword"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_red"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In  your AndroidManifest try adjusting your softInputMode value in your activity tag to only "adjustResize"

e.g.

```
<activity
 android:name="YourActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

I think the issue may be because you have the other options available since the "adjustPan" option allows your keyboard to rest on top of your layout

Comment: No.. I checked.... its not working.. Shall I ask .. one thing do we need to make our parent view scrollview..my parent view is relative layout

Comment: No you shouldn't have to wrap everything in a scrollview since that flag handles that. Have you tried commenting out that "getWindow.." function you placed in the onCreate since you made the change in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just this :

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```